# why the outcome of applying dtype and type function on pandas column gives different outcome?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am getting different result when applying dtype and type function separately on same pandas column.So,I want to know where it is suitable to use dtype and type function on pandas dataframe.

```
[In]:type(zostel_df['id'])
[out]: pandas.core.series.Series
[In]: zostel_df['id'].dtype
[out]: dtype('int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

dtype `returns the dtype object of the underlying data` -> if you give it pandas column full of integers then it will return pandas type int equivalent. it looks inside the object types and returns type of its data and not the object type itself.

while

type `returns the object's type` if you give it pandas column that is effectively a series then it returns Series as the object type. it does not look inside its type but it returns its type only.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.dtype
```

will show the type of the column which is basically pandas series.It can contain text or numbers it will remain pandas.Series whereas

```
type(data)
```

will show the type of data that columns contains i.e. it can contain int,object,float etc.